# When I am going to use Android Device Monitor File Explorer,It shows nothing. I'm using Nexus 5x Api 26 oreo.How to fix this issue?

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

When I am going to use Android Device Monitor File Explorer, It shows nothing. I'm using Nexus 5x API 26 oreo.How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with new release. Kindly connect Api 24 or below device or emulator then you will see the file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access files and data from **Device file explorer** in the android studio. you do not need to check in Android device manager.

Please check screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can get it in android device monitor file explorer?

Comment: It will show when your emulator or device is connected.